# Stack overflow on hibernate caused by one to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, lombok

I have created a one to many relationship. Although everything seems fine when I query the objects by id from the many to one side, the joined column throws a stackoverflow exception, that I cannot figure out why it happens. Roughly I have followed [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-oracle).

Player Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "player_id", updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "num")
    private int num;
    @Column(name = "position")
    private String position;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;
}
```

Team Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Team {
    @Id
    @Column(name="team_id", updatable = false, unique = true)
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Player> players;
}
```

My player repository

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends CrudRepository<Player, Long> {
    Optional<Player> findById(Long id);
}
```

Database entries in import.sql

```
insert into Team (team_id,name) values('Barcelona','Barcelona');
insert into Player (name,num,position,team_id) values('Andreas Inniesta', 8, 'Midfielder', 'Barcelona');
insert into Player (name,num,position,team_id) values('Lionel Messi', 10, 'Forward', 'Barcelona');
```

The player table at h2-console
[image]

This is the exception

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at mypackage.entity.Player.toString(Player.java:8) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at mypackage.entity.Team.toString(Team.java:9) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at mypackage.entity.Team_$$_jvst2b7_1.toString(Team_$$_jvst2b7_1.java) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at mypackage.entity.Player.toString(Player.java:8) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at mypackage.entity.Team.toString(Team.java:9) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at mypackage.entity.Team_$$_jvst2b7_1.toString(Team_$$_jvst2b7_1.java) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at mypackage.entity.Player.toString(Player.java:8) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at mypackage.entity.Team.toString(Team.java:9) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at mypackage.entity.Team_$$_jvst2b7_1.toString(Team_$$_jvst2b7_1.java) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at mypackage.entity.Player.toString(Player.java:8) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at mypackage.entity.Team.toString(Team.java:9) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Root of the exception

```
at mypackage.entity.Team.toString(Team.java:9) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
at mypackage.entity.Team_$$_jvst2b7_1.toString(Team_$$_jvst2b7_1.java) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at mypackage.entity.Player.toString(Player.java:8) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at mypackage.entity.Team.toString(Team.java:9) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Furthermore debugging the error shows that some kind of internal conversion to string fails on the joined column.
[image]

Comment: The exception states that the error is in `Player.toString()` so you should show us that method. I suspect that it is calling `Team.toString()` which in turn calls `Player.toString()` and thus causes the stack overflow. Can you post both methods?

Comment: I have not overriden these methods, the error happens internally in the `@Repository`. I assumed that i have made a mistake, if that is not the case I have run into a bug.

Comment: Can you expand the stack trace?

Comment: @J-Alex I cannot post the whole thing, because of character limitation, I expanded it by quite a bit. If you want the start of it let me know.

Comment: yeah.. paste root cause and also can you try to add fetchType = Lazy for Players in Team object.

Comment: @J-Alex I added the root and rerun it with Lazy. Same result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I can see you're using `Lombok`.

You think that you're not creating `toString` method, but `Lombok` doesn't think so. The `@Data` annotation causes generation of `toString` method.

From `Lombok` documentation:

> `@Data` is a convenient shortcut annotation that bundles the features of
>   `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@Getter` / `@Setter` and
>   `@RequiredArgsConstructor` together: In other words, `@Data` generates all
>   the boilerplate that is normally associated with simple POJOs (Plain
>   Old Java Objects) and beans: getters for all fields, setters for all
>   non-final fields, and appropriate toString, equals and hashCode
>   implementations that involve the fields of the class, and a
>   constructor that initializes all final fields, as well as all
>   non-final fields with no initializer that have been marked with
>   `@NonNull`, in order to ensure the field is never null.

So `Lombok` created `toString` method for you which leads to infinite recursion.

You can fix it by:

```
@Data
@ToString(exclude = "players")
public class Team {
   // ...
}
```

Or:

```
@Data
public class Team {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Player> players;
}
```

Worth to mention, if you still need include `players` in the `Team`'s `toString` representation, try to disassemble the `@Data` annotation and add only the parts you really need. Then define your own `toString` method.

Comment: I did not expect Lombok to "sabotage" me, excluding the toString worked. I consider to remove it alltogether. Thank you.

Comment: by excluding players from @ToString we will not able to to console the value of player. We have to understand why ToString() method is getting called for the Team Object right?

Comment: @Hareesh Maybe, but I am not using console anyway. I don't have the exception anymore. Like I said on my previous comment probably I will remove Lombok alltogether, since it causes problems in that case.

Comment: @Hareesh Then one need to define custom `toString` method and take care of this himself.

Comment: Okay thats also one of the option. But what is eating my head is where toString() method call is made. As per @Dimitris, he is not calling toString() method.

Comment: Internally in hibernate when the repository interface method findById(id) gets invoked.  `org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString`

Comment: `toString()` can be called in a number of situations, e.g. when trying to log something. I'd _never_ rely on `toString()` not being called in any case, so fixing it is the only sensible approach.

Answer (score 3):

Even i faced similar problem. I got StackoverFlow Error while trying to persist one to many relationship.
The solution was.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "players")   // players is @OneToMany
 class Team {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
   private List<Player> players;
 }
```

This was causing issue because it used to create hashcode using all the entities. This lead to recursion.

Comment: Previous solution doesn't work for me, but this one does. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because when you want to query the Team, say, team 'A', it also carries a list of Players who are in team 'A', which themselves carry the Team they are in(team 'A'), which also carries a list of Players... You get it, it infinitely cycles through this relationship with no end. To avoid a StackOverflow error, you need to annotate the side of @OneToMany with @JsonIgnore if you are using Jackson, or @JsonbTransient if you use plain jsonb.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Player> players;
```

OR

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
@JsonbTransient
private List<Player> players;
```

This way, when querying a team, the list of players will be ignored and you will avoid the error.