# Postman is not updating my mariadb dataabase in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mariadb, postman

I am writing a rest api, but when I try to test it in Postman none of the requests are going through.  When I click the send button nothing gets updates in the database. I am not getting any errors from the spring server, nor any from Postman.  Here are my files:

Student.java

```
package StudentModel;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {
    public enum status {
        PAID,
        UNPAID,
        PARTIAL
    }
    
    @Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long Id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String FirstName;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String LastName;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long Phone;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String Email;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private status PaymentStatus;

    public long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(long phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public status getPaymentStatus() {
        return PaymentStatus;
    }

    public void setPaymentStatus(status paymentStatus) {
        PaymentStatus = paymentStatus;
    }   
}
```

StudentController.java:

```
package StudentController;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import StudentModel.Student;
import StudentService.StudentService;

@RestController
public class StudentController {
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    
    @PostMapping("/addStudent")
    public Student addStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    return studentService.saveStudent(student);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/addStudents")
    public List<Student> addStudents(@RequestBody List<Student> students) {
        return studentService.saveStudents(students);
        }
    @GetMapping("/students")
    public List<Student> findAllStudents(){
        return studentService.getStudents();
    }
    @GetMapping("/students/{id}")
    public Student findStudentById(@PathVariable long id) {
        return studentService.getStudentById(id);
    }
    @GetMapping("/students/{name}")
    public Student findStudentByFirstName(@PathVariable String FirstName) {
        return studentService.getStudentByFirstName(FirstName);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/update")
    public Student updateStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    return studentService.updateStudent(student);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteStudent(@PathVariable long id) {
        return studentService.deleteStudent(id);
    }   
}
```

StudentService.java:

```
package StudentService;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import StudentModel.Student;
import StudentRepository.StudentRepository;

@Service
public class StudentService {
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
    
    public Student saveStudent(Student student) {
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }
    
    public List<Student> saveStudents(List<Student> students) {
        return studentRepository.saveAll(students);
    }
    
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Student getStudentById(long id){
        return studentRepository.findById(id);
    }
    
    public Student getStudentByFirstName(String FirstName){
        return studentRepository.findByFirstName(FirstName);
    }
    
    public Student getStudentByLastName(String LastName){
        return studentRepository.findByLastName(LastName);
    }
    
    public Student getStudentByEmail(String Email){
        return studentRepository.findByEmail(Email);
    }
    
    public Student getStudentByPhone(long Phone){
        return studentRepository.findByPhone(Phone);
    }
    
    public String deleteStudent(long id) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "Student Deleted";
    }
    
    public Student updateStudent (Student student) {
        Student existingStudent = studentRepository.findById(student.getId());
        existingStudent.setFirstName(student.getFirstName());
        existingStudent.setLastName(student.getLastName());
        existingStudent.setEmail(student.getEmail());
        existingStudent.setPhone(student.getPhone());
        existingStudent.setPaymentStatus(student.getPaymentStatus());
        return studentRepository.save(existingStudent);
    }
}
```

StudentRepository:

```
package StudentRepository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import StudentModel.Student;

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository <Student, Long>{
    Student saveStudent (Student student);
    Student findByFirstName(String FirstName);
    Student findByLastName(String LastName);
    Student findByEmail(String Email);
    Student findByPhone(long Phone);

    Student findById(long id);
}
```

StudentApplication.java:

```
package com.BusyQA;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class BusyQaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BusyQaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'm at a total loss at what to do here.  I've attempted borrowing from other posts, but they don't seem to work for me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `findById` and `saveStudent` use `save` instead. Also mark your service with `@Transactional` and remove `@EnableJpaRepositories` from your spring boot application class.

Comment: You do not need the @Data annotation you have getters and setters and in the data you override the stringof. I had problems with that in tha past. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570757/stack-overflow-on-hibernate-caused-by-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: I would suggest you start with debugging. Add a breakpoint in your controller. Check that the body arrives correctly as you expect it. then move on with your breakpoints and see if that data are all as expected. The suggestions from @M.Deinum are also good. You do not need to rewrite out of the box functions.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Postman it at least now giving me some feedback.  Unfortunately, all my requests now return a 404 error.  I'll try to wrangle with it, but in the mean time any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.